# I am having command line problems in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, command-line

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and trying to enter this command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa`,  but then it asks for my password and I can't type anything. The only thing I can do is press <kbd>enter</kbd>, and then it says incorrect password. Please help!

Comment: When you type in your password in Terminal, nothing shows up. So type in your password and press Enter to continue.

Answer (score 3):

If you entered this command in the terminal, you just enter your password. It won't indicate that it receives anything but validates it when you press <kbd>RETURN</kbd>

If you have graphical UI you can use `gksudo` instead and it will prompt you for password in a more graphical manner. Try this:

> gksudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa